# Move a div to another div on a specific time frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like on 7 am in the morning the code runs and moves a div to another div

here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var tomorrow_sec = jQuery("#day").html();
  jQuery("#day-dest").html(tomorrow_sec);
  jQuery("#day").html(" ");
});
```

Comment: you need to apply jquery setTimeout - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @AlokMali setTimeout is not jQuery

Comment: So you are planning to have the page loaded in the browser at all time and then check the time at intervals to see if it is 7am and then move a div? How can we help when you are posting no example of your HTML and give so little detail?

Comment: thanks @AlokMali It was my first question here in stack. how can I do it with setTimeout

Comment: @mplungjan I am working on wordpress site and it is Post grid which I want to move   to another post grid at 7. post grid the moving with jquery but I am not able to add time condition to it. I have shared my j query code

Comment: I have mentioned the URL. You need to create a function which checks the current time, and if the time is equal to your specified time then do your code.

Comment: can you amend this function to my  j query code please

Comment: Sorry, My mistake you can use setInterval. I am posting an answer, hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The code will run when you load the page.
If you want to move something, then you need to check every time you load the page what the time is, and then try to open in x milliseconds OR you need to run an interval and see if the time has been reached.

Method one:

```
$(function(){
  var now = new Date(); // or new Date(time in milliseconds from server)
  var sevenAm = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),7,0,0,0)
  var diff = sevenAm.getTime() - now.getTime();
  if (diff < 0) sevenAm.setDate(sevenAm.getDate()+1); // tomorrow
  diff = sevenAm.getTime() - now.getTime(); 
  var tId = setTimeout(function() {
      var tomorrow_sec = $("#day").html();
      $("#day-dest").html(tomorrow_sec);
      $("#day").empty();
  },diff);
});
```

Method 2

```js
$(function() {
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var sevenAm = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 7, 0, 0, 0)
    var diff = sevenAm.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (diff < 0) sevenAm.setDate(sevenAm.getDate() + 1); // tomorrow
    diff = sevenAm.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (diff <= 60000) { // within a minute - you could use Math.abs here
      var tomorrow_sec = $("#day").html();
      $("#day-dest").html(tomorrow_sec);
      $("#day").empty();
    }
  }, 1000); // 30000: test every 30 seconds
});
```

Comment: It takes Current time like which I have set on my pc or it takes from server?

Comment: Thanks I have tried both methods doesn't work for me

Comment: You can change `var now = new Date(); ` to `var now = new Date(<?= $servertimeinmilliseconds ?>); `

Comment: I had a spelling mistake in setDate

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing in the back-end.I am using wp bakery builder wordpress. I'll really appreciate your answer

Comment: I have no experience with WP so I cannot help you there

Comment: Perhaps https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event

Answer (score 0):

Set an interval on page load, which will run on every 1 second. and will check the time. If the time is 07:00 am to 09:59 am then it will remove content from a div and paste into another div.

You can check the working fiddle here - [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/db5e7gnh/3/)

To test it, uncomment the line `var today = new Date('01/01/2011 07:00:00');` and comment the next line `var today = new Date();`

```js
var interval = setInterval(myfunction, 1000);

function myfunction() {
  //var today = new Date('01/01/2011 07:00:00');
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
  //console.log(time);
  if (time >= '7:0' && time <= '9:30') {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var tomorrow_sec = jQuery("#day").html();
    jQuery("#day-dest").html(tomorrow_sec);
    jQuery("#day").html("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="day">
  content of day div
</div>

<div id="day-dest">
  fghgjgh
</div>
```

Comment: "10:0" is < "7:0" so that is a poor test

Comment: @mplungjan, can you suggest a better way to compare it. It will be helpful for me as well.

Comment: @AlokMali can we do it in that way so It can only run at 7 am after 7 when I update the second div It'll be updated next day at 7 Am.. right now when I update second div it is moving instantly

Comment: I am using WpBakary page builder. is it possible to move content of one dive into another one using jquery? yes, right now Its working on the front end but in the builder the content doesn't really move to the div.

Comment: @AlokMali Is it possible that we can't  change anything in the div between 7 to 10

Comment: @mplungjan are you there?

Comment: @AlokMali can we change time to 7 am to 9.30am instead of 9.59 am please reply ASAP

Comment: You can put it in the `if` condition. I am updating my answer, please try it.

Comment: @AlokMali can we add a button or anything on front end to turn it off when require?means the code will be running until we click on the button to switch it off..

Comment: @AlokMali Could you please help me with this